# How to move files with date using plink

Tags: shell, batch-file, plink

I want to move the files with current date using plink

```
 @ECHO OFF
plink administrator@10.7.20.214 -pw TestPa (mv /home/shared/administrator/scripts/sam  /home/shared/administrator/scripts/sam_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M"`)`
```

But at the output file is updated as sam_mHM. I want it to be sam_20191218_1422

Answer (score 0):

You have to double the `%` symbols to get them through a local batch file interpreter to the server.

```
plink username@example.com -pw password (mv /path/sam /path/sam_`date +"%%Y%%m%%d_%%H%%M"`)
```

---

Alternatively, you can format the timestamp locally in the batch file instead of using the remote `date` command:
[How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/850848)